# Query relaxation - change constraints

Tags: java, database, algorithm, networking, bayesian

This is a new field to me and I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for.
I need to change the constraints when querying a database. An example of this is a job search web app. If a user is searching for jobs in a 50 mile radius with certain characteristics, I need to get jobs that are not a perfect match but also very relevant to him.

If there is a job for the user that's almost 100% match but it's 52 miles away, I need it also to be retrieved to be presented to the user (considering it's relevance since 2 miles in 50 is only 4% more).

The idea is to develop a new job search web app and hopefully it will grow. The companies create their jobs offers on the site and these are searched by the users. It's pretty much the usual. The difference is in the search mechanism. It's a little more clever than the simple db query, that's why I need to know how to get more results to filter them after.
If there is a limit like (select * from jobs where salary > 25000 or salary < 26000), a job that is 100% match but the salary is 24999, will not show up in the results although it should because it's close.
The idea is to get all the jobs in the db that are close (so for that I have to relax the constraints to larger values), the through a bayesian network or something, determine it's relevance to the user. Of course these conditions also apply for the other job attributes like location, experience, job area (comp sci, mechanics, etc.)

So I need some pointers where to look for more information on this subject, how to relax these constraints to make a wider search and then through a bayesian network calculate the relevance to user and show it.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: You should first give us much more information on the problem: what is the scale (how many jobs are we talking about?) What is the data structure? (or is it flexible and changeable)? Are you indexing your information from non-structured data? (like texts)? Or is it fed structured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach is to do a quick first stage search that might let through some rubbish and then to do a more detailed check on what you get from that. In your example, you might simply change the query terms by 10% each way, so (select * from jobs where salary > 25000 or salary < 26000) becomes (select * from jobs where salary > 22500 or salary < 23400) - did you really mean or here, by the way, or should that be and?.

Then take the answers that pass the first stage and sort them by something like the sum of the squares of the percentage difference from the ideal value, and show the user the top N answers. That's simple, and you might be able to find an argument involving the normal distribution which justifies it as a Bayesian calculation of something or other.

Comment: I've been searching a little more and this is indeed the way to do it since there is nothing formal on this matter. It's like trial and error and common sense. Thank you